# simple github actions workflow to run nuget does not work: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: nuget, certificate, github-actions

I am trying to make a github actions workflow that will create a nuget package using the nuget CLI. I have a very simple small github actions workflow that just clones and runs the command 'nuget' which prints the version info and so on. Here is my workflow:

```
name: NuGet APIKey Secret

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: martin-laptop
    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@master
        - uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
          with:
            nuget-version: '5.x'
        - run: nuget
```

it runs on my local laptop 'martin-laptop', which is setup to be a github actions runner. But when I run this workflow, I get an error on the run nuget/nuget-setup build step:

```
Run nuget/setup-nuget@v1
  with:
    nuget-version: 5.x
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Is this something with my local wifi? I'm on my own wifi hotspot connected with a cisco vpn. Is this local issuer certificate issue saying there is something wrong with my local machine runner (running on command prompt)? this exact workflow as worked once, then never again, even though i changed nothing.

Comment: Is this a corporate laptop? Maybe ask your IT department if they use a corporate mitm proxy on the system. But yes, this is a local system issue, not necessarily a problem with the action.